What are the services that track the user's settings on Gnome (e.g. Dark mode)?
I have a installation of Fedora 40 with Gnome and I've installed i3 and started configuring it.
On Gnome when I switch to dark mode my apps like the Chrome browser pick up this change automatically but not on i3.
On Gnome I switch to dark mode using the top right menu and on i3 I use these commands:
# Dark mode.
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme Adwaita-dark
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme prefer-dark
# Light mode.
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme Adwaita
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme prefer-light

I've also tested these commands on Gnome and they're working just like the UI button to switch to dark mode.
What I have observed:
If I log in to i3 directly on boot and change the theme, it won't be applied.
If I log in to Gnome first on boot and then log out and log in to i3 then theme switching works.
I'm assuming that there's a service running that's started on Gnome to track these settings, I want to start this service from my i3 config to be able to switch the theme.
I've checked the systemd services using systemctl --user list-units and found out that there are 5 services less when logging in to i3 directly and one of them is dconf.service which I tried to start but didn't change anything.

I don't know because I don't use Gnome but you could run strace -f gsettings and see what files or sockets are used and then check what other services use them.

After searching for some time, I managed to make it work using 2 methods that configure xdg-desktop-portal:
1. Force a desktop environment
Override the systemd xdg-desktop-portal.service to set the environment variable XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP by creating a file at ~/.config/systemd/user/xdg-desktop-portal.service.d/override.conf :
[Service]
Environment="XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=gnome"

This way you don't have to change the global XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP which will still be i3.
Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_Desktop_Portal#Force_desktop_environment
2. Change the default portal backend
Create an xdg-desktop-portal config at ~/.config/xdg-desktop-portal/portal.conf with the following:
[preferred]
default=gtk

This config file seems to be overriding the default value defined at /usr/share/xdg-desktop-portal/gnome-portals.conf:
[preferred]
default=gnome;gtk;
org.freedesktop.impl.portal.Secret=gnome-keyring;

Sources:

https://github.com/i3/i3/discussions/5896
https://discourse.gnome.org/t/using-adwaita-dark-on-another-compositor/17563/10

